# Neutron collision in the laboratory and center-of-mass reference frames

Tags: nuclear-physics, scattering, neutrons, nuclear-engineering

In most reactor theory books I find a statement that neutrons are assumed to elastically scatter isotropically in the laboratory frame of reference. Can someone show in a diagram the two systems (laboratory and center-of-mass) elastic collisions and explanation. I want to visualize and compare both systems.

Answer (score 1):

The assumption that neutron scattering is isotropic (or $s$-wave, or "the Born approximation works") is quite good for low-energy neutrons in the center-of-mass frame of the scattering process, but it can also be reasonable in the lab frame depending on the mass of the scatterer.

Neutron scattering occurs entirely due to the neutron's interaction with the nucleus, and all nuclei other than hydrogen are heavier than the neutron by at least a factor of two.  So for instance if you are interested in fast (but nonrelativistic) reactor neutrons being moderated by interaction with boron-10, the transformation to the center-of-mass frame involves changing the neutron's speed by only about 10%.  For neutrons scattering from uranium the transition to the lab frame is equivalent to adjusting the neutron's speed by less than 0.5%.

For fast neutrons scattering from hydrogen, as in a water moderator, the assumption that the lab frame and the center-of-mass frame are identical is markedly poorer, since the neutron and the proton have essentially equal masses.
In the center-of-mass frame, the scattering is still elastic, and also isotropic:
if the neutron is incident from the left, it's equally likely to exit to the left or the right (with the transverse component of the scattered momentum fixed by energy conservation).
A 90° deflection in the center-of-mass frame corresponds to the proton and neutron sharing their kinetic energy equally after the collision in the lab frame, so the neutron will lose on average half its energy in each collision.
But from fission energies (few mega-eV) to liquid hydrogen energies (few milli-eV) takes only about thirty factor-of-two collisions.
Once the neutrons have thermalized, random motion of the scatterers will typically balance out neutron's momentum and the center-of-mass frame becomes the same as the lab frame again.

Comment: Can you kindly tell from which formulas I can compare both frames for above examples of boron and uranium.

Comment: Total momentum for a two-particle system is $\vec p_\text{total} = m_1 \vec v_1 + m_2 \vec v_2$.  Lab frame has the target at rest; center-of-mass frame has total momentum zero.

Comment: Okay I get it, I will ask you again but first I read again about collision kinematics. One more clarification. Can you kindly explain what is meant by isotropic source and isotropin scattering.

Comment: By [isotropic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropy) I mean the same in all directions.  So for scattering from a single hydrogen nucleus at rest the neutron distribution can't be isotropic, since there's no way to conserve energy and momentum and have the neutron end up going backwards. But for scattering from uranium, the neutron is more or less equally likely to scatter forwards or backwards, so isotropy is a good approximation.

Comment: One note, the neutron can lose all its energy in a collision with a proton. Not true for heavier nuclei.  Most neutron shields have a lot of hydrogen in them. Parrafin, water, etc.. Think of two billiard balls.  One can transfer all energy and momentum to another.

Comment: @john Well, a neutron that stopped in a billiard-ball-type collision with a proton in paraffin would probably get upscattered by the thermal motion of the next proton it happened to meet --- in an directionally isotropic way. Contrast with [billiard-ball collisions between neutrons and phonons in helium](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0204635), where the phonons run away to the refrigerator.